# Assignment/allocation of tasks in hosts

Tags: python, variable-assignment, hungarian-algorithm

I have a set of hosts and a set of tasks.
Each host has cpu, mem and task capacities and each task has cpu, mem requirements.
Each host belongs to a latency class and may communicate with other hosts with a certain latency value.
Each task may require to communicate with another task with a latency equal or less to a certain value.
An example of my problem input is shown in the next image.[image: Task and host graphs.]
where task t1 requires to communicate with tasks t2, t3 and t4 with a latency equal or less than 3, 3 and 5 respectively and host h1 belongs to a latency class 3 and communicates with h2, h3 and h4 with latencies 2, 5, and 3 respectively.
I was thinking to solve this problem using the Hungarian/munkres algorithm but how can i set a cost function properly?
Is there a better assignment algorithm to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python package for Munkres: http://software.clapper.org/munkres/. You may refer to their implementation: https://github.com/bmc/munkres/blob/master/munkres.py

Answer (score 1):

As you should know, this problem is a case of the QAP (Quadratic Assignment Problem) and this is NP complete, which means in few words: there isn't exist the best algorithm for solving it, at least in polynomial time. More details [here](http://www.assignmentproblems.com)

Though, there are several approachs to deal with, I've tried some simple methods from the AI like Genetic Algorithms (GA) and ACO with great results. I would recommend you GA for.